# MATLAB function to reassign values of undefined number of variables

Tags: matlab, variadic-functions

I want to write a MATLAB function that can take an undefined number of variables, change their values, and output them under the same names. I got part way there if I don't mind listing the variables twice:

```
function [varargout]=testing(varargin)
    for i=1:nargin
        varargout{i}=varargin{i}*2;
    end
end
```

and

```
x=5;
y=3;
z=6;
[x,y,z]=testing(x,y,z);
```

But I don't want to list the variable names twice. Is there anyway I can call the function like this instead?

```
testing(x,y,z);
```

I tried using inputname, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blindly adjusting values across workspaces is highly unadvisable and can lead to hard to detect bugs and make the code difficult to maintain. Arguments against this essentially mirror [arguments against global variables](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad). It will be far more reliable to explicitly control the data you want to manipulate. Yes, this will probably require you to store your data differently.

For example, you can use a [structure](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html):

```
function testcode()
mydata.a = 1;
mydata.b = 2;
mydata.c = 3;
mydata.d = 4;

mydata = multiplydata(mydata, 2);
disp(mydata)
end

function [datastruct] = multiplydata(datastruct, n)
varnames = fieldnames(datastruct);
for ii = 1:length(varnames)
    datastruct.(varnames{ii}) = datastruct.(varnames{ii})*n;
end
end
```

Which outputs:

```
>> testcode
    a: 2
    b: 4
    c: 6
    d: 8
```

This isn't really any functionally different than using `varargin`/`varargout`, but if you write your code in such a way that you're utilizing structures from the beginning, you don't have to deal with the extra unpacking step (e.g. `x = varargin{1}`, etc.).

---

If, for whatever reason, you absolutely *must* blindly adjust your variables (which, again, please don't), then you can use [`assignin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html):

```
function testcode()
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
d = 4;

multiplydata(2, a, b, c, d);
fprintf('a: %u\nb: %u\nc: %u\nd: %u\n', a, b, c, d)
end

function multiplydata(n, varargin)
for ii = 1:length(varargin)
    varname = inputname(ii + 1);
    assignin('caller', varname, varargin{ii}*n)
end
end
```

Which returns:

```
>> testcode
a: 2
b: 4
c: 6
d: 8
```